# Shared Preferences issue when using github and Android device

Tags: android, github, sharedpreferences, tablet

I am testing my code for an Android app using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. I am using Shared Preferences to store a username and password on the device. I am working with Github as this is a team project. When I save settings into Shared Preferences in an older version of the code and then try to use a newer version, I am getting a null pointer exception. This doesn't happen when I uninstall the app and use the newer version. In this case, everything seems to be working fine. The newer version has some new key value pairs being stored in Shared Preferences. Can somebody please let me know why this is happening and what I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` are stored on the device and kept there if you update the app. The key / value pairs stored there won't update the key automagically if you change it in code. Uninstalling the app on the other hand will remove every app setting, i.e. your `SharedPreferences`.

If the newer version looks for data stored with a a new key it won't find anything if it was stored with the old key and will return `null`. That's most likely the NPE you are experiencing.

You could check for both keys (preferring the new key if it exists) and keep compatibility with your old version that way.

Apart from that you should always expect to get `null` and handle it in a safe way since the user can clear the app settings at any time.